# Nested quotes mvc

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem about nested quotes.

```
 <td style="width: 7%;padding-left:30px"><span class="btn btn-succes mainButton" data-toggle="modal" onclick="showStudents(@ViewBag.Acts[i].ActId, '@ViewBag.Acts[i].ActName','@ViewBag.Acts[i].Filter')" style="float: left; background: bisque"><i class="fa fa-sitemap"> Classes</i></span></td>
```

Above I have an  code and it opens a modal. but it doesn't work. Because @ViewBag.Acts[i].ActName includes separation sign. so

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

error occurs.

Comment: i have tested it and it works for me , check your viewbag ti see if the data is supplied correctly

Comment: The problem is not originating from nested quotes, the razor engine is capable of recognizing @ variable under nested quotes

Comment: It work if @ViewBag.Acts[i].ActName doesnt include ' sign. Problem is when string includes ' sign

Comment: can you post values of each ActId, ActName and Filter please, i bet one of the has a single quote in it ( i suspect Filter )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you may be talking about is that the value of the variable itself contains a quote. For example, if the value of `ViewBag.Acts[i].ActName` was `Foo's`, then once Razer finished rendering the view you'd have something like:

```
onclick="showStudents(1, 'Foo's', ...
```

Obviously, that's a syntax error. The only thing that you can do in this situation is to escape the quotes:

```
onclick="showStudents(@ViewBag.Acts[i].ActId, '@ViewBag.Acts[i].ActName.Replace("'", "\\'")', ...
```

Which would result in:

```
onclick="showStudents(1, 'Foo\'s', ...
```

And you should be fine. You'll probably also need to do the same for double quotes, so you don't mess up the `onclick` attribute. You just need to keep in mind that all Razor is doing is just dumping the value of the variable as-is among the rest of the HTML, JavaScript, whatever, so you have to think about what that would look like as just straight HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot single quote for first parameter of `showStudents`:

```
...onclick="showStudents('@ViewBag.Acts[i].ActId'...
```

Comment: It work if @ViewBag.Acts[i].ActName doesnt include ' sign. Problem is when string includes ' sign